# Edit way directory is invoked on server

Tags: .htaccess

What I'm trying to do seems very simple, but I did not yet find the solution. The idea is that a specific directory on my server can only be opened through one URL. Currently, the website can be accessed by navigating to `http://dir.mydomain.com` as well as `http://mydomain.com/dir`. All links use the first option, but to prevent search engines from detecting duplicate content and my users from getting confused I'd like to simply disable the second option. I would swear that I have read something about a solution some time, but I can't remember it or find it back... Hope you can help me fixing this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try looking for helpful information in [the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just redirect with a 301 to `dir.mydomain.com` so whatever links to the 2nd get mapped to the 1st?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dir
RewriteRule ^dir http://dir.mydomain.com [R=301]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I were looking for. I did multiple attempts to do the trick, but didn't come up with line 2 and 3. Thanks for this final push. Problem solved!